# Display Comments posts wise

Tags: php, wordpress

I called the function `<?php comment_form(); ?>` in my page template. It is displaying "Leave a Comment" form.

When i comment through the form, page redirecting to original page from my page template. How can i display all the comments by post wise with out page redirecting?

[image]

Comment: hi,
to avoid your redirect please use ajax so you can stop redirecting.

Comment: How to do with AJAX? Please..